# "Too many open files/watchers" in Fedora/Linux

Tags: linux

I have a "bare metal" machine with Fedora 31 installed.

When I use VSCode remote, every 1~2 hour, I cannot run commands like `tail -f` or `journalctl` or `podman` anymore. (VSCode terminal and SSH)

I can kill vscode server to resolve this (temporary). I think the vscode server is leaking fds, but can not find why.

I followed every article I can found from google, but failed to resolve this.

`sysctl fs.file-nr`:

```
fs.file-nr = 10512      0       2000000
```

This command: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752067/counting-open-files-per-process/21752125#21752125

```
194 fds (PID = 4313), command: /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr
141 fds (PID = 1), command: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --switched-root --system --deserialize 29
119 fds (PID = 3448), command: /usr/bin/qbittorrent --profile=/opt
90 fds (PID = 18100), command: /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
72 fds (PID = 1180), command: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
57 fds (PID = 8781), command: /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no-process-group
52 fds (PID = 3976), command: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd
47 fds (PID = 3785), command: /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
43 fds (PID = 1758), command: dbus-broker --log 4 --controller 9 --machine-id 48d17ca8e2184a66b9043781fdc8f037 --max-bytes 536870912 --max-fds 4096 --max-matches 16384 --audit
40 fds (PID = 1766096), command: /root/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/node /root/.vscode-server/bin/26076a4de974ead31f97692a0d32f90d735645c0/out/vs/server/main.js --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remote-auto-shutdown --port=0
```

`ulimit -n`

```
500000
```

`lsof | awk '{print $9}' | sort | uniq | wc -l`

```
2003
```

And memory is large enough:
`free -g`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:             59           8           6           0          44          50
Swap:            63           0          63
```

After kill vscode server:
`sysctl fs.file-nr`

```
fs.file-nr = 10320      0       2000000
```

You can see the total open file is a "tiny" number (comapre to some high load server).
And vscode server is using only 40 fds, but after I kill it, file-nr decrease more than 200. Is that possible??

I'm using the `root` user and disabled SELinux, is there anything else can limit my resource usage?